# Google maps like image tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image, iis

I am trying to create an interactive image on my page like Google maps for use with my own images.

I would like to have similar functions including drag, scroll, zoom in/out.

Are there any tools or plugins I can use?

My environment consists of IIS Server, ASP.NET, JavaScript, and jQuery.

Comment: Certainly there are tools.  However, if you provide more information about your environment, it would help us help you.

Comment: I want to present my images (big/small) to customer on part of my one web page.I need the web page works cross browser.User can navigate (drag,zoom in/out) my images same as google map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

[Overscroll](http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll) jQuery plugin

[DimViewer](http://www.dimviewer.com/)

[OpenLayers](http://www.OpenLayers.org/)

They  have the features you are looking for.

Comment: Off all 3, only OpenLayers seems to remain a valid option. DimViewer is paid and feels super clumsy.